# I can execute Main.java file but not Main.class file

Tags: java, file, class, package

I am learning Java and I have some difficulties with the package mechanism. I have different classes in a package. I compiled it right but when I execute the Main file I have a different behavior. *Music3* is the file where is the main method.

```
andrea@andrea:~/Documenti/java$ java -Xdiag  -cp class/ source/Music3
Errore: impossibile trovare o caricare la classe principale source.Music3
Causato da: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: source.Music3
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: source.Music3
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:791)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:686)
andrea@andrea:~/Documenti/java$ java -Xdiag  -cp class/ source/Music3.java
Wind.play() C_Sharp
Percussion.play() C_Sharp
Stringed.play() C_Sharp
```

As you can see I have the right output when I execute Music3.java. What is wrong?

Answer (score -1):

The `java` command takes a class name, *not* a file name: It's `java -Xdiag -cp class source.Music3`.

Note that 'source' is an extremely unfortunate package name, pick something else. Say it's 'sposito', then your source file should be in `project/src/sposito/Music3.java`, have `package sposito;` compile it someplace so that the class file ends up in `project/class/sposito/Music3.class`, run it from the `project` dir with `java -cp class sposito.Music3`.